# in Google Apps Script; using Regular Expression & Conditional formatting - to create a IPv4 address validator / checker

Tags: regex, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

## in Google Apps Script; using Regular Expression & Conditional formatting - to create a IPv4 address validaton / checker

### 1. VALIDATING the input with regular expression :

I try to make a script to get feedback of a validator, to check if the input an IP addresses is.

#### regular expression pattern :

cell ' ip!I12 '  named  ' REGEXP_IP_pattern ' :

`^((((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([01]?[0-9]{1,2}))\.){3}((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([01]?[0-9]{1,2})))`

[reg exp demo](https://regexr.com/54fon) : https://regexr.com/54fon - works fine (in the formula)

#### formula in the cell :

[image: in the spreadsheet - formuala]

works in the formula fine, but I have to work with formulas in formulas to define if the status is valid or not.

The regular expression in formula format works fine [see worksheet '`ip`'], but the sad thing is that I fail to get it working in the script.
Have some issues to retrieve the correct and good information, to define if a input 'ip' is valid or not. *(see column 'input' , 'good ip')*

in the formula : 
`=IF( REGEXREPLACE(TRIM( <cell> &"");REGEXP_IP_pattern;wildChar_IP) = wildChar_IP;1;0)`

- to force and cast the cell to a string : `TRIM( <cell> &"")`
- 'remove' the founded regexpmatch and on the rest of the string add a '`wildChar_IP`' [a wild character]
- check if the rest is '*nothing*' (in our case equal to the '`wildChar_IP`')

#### script / code :

For the Google Apps Script, **TOOLS** > **SCRIPT EDITOR**

To see the output of the logger : **VIEW** > **LOGBOOK**

**So how is it possible to get feedback, status, if it *only* matches with regular expression in a function?**

for example a boolean as return.

This is my code ... but fails to define when it really matches.
Because of autosense/autocomplete is not really reliable, is there an other way to find out all method of

`var regExp = new RegExp(regExpPattIP, "gi");
var result01 = regExp.exec(ip01);`

code :

```
var ip01 ='256.12.2.0'
var ip02 ='255.12.2.0'
var ip03 ='192.168..1'
var ip04 ='10.12.12.12.12'
var ip05 ='010.060.090.002'



function validatorRegExp() {

  //var regExpPattIP ="^((((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([01]?[0-9]{1,2}))\.){3}((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([01]?[0-9]{1,2})))";
  var regExpPattIP = actSheet.getRangeByName(RegExp_patt_IP).getValue();

  var regExp = new RegExp(regExpPattIP, "gi");  // "i" is for case insensitive --  "g" is for global
  var result01 = regExp.exec(ip01);
  console.log(" --- ip01: ", ip01, "---");
  console.log(result01);
  var result02 = regExp.exec(ip02);
  console.log(" --- ip02: ", ip02, "---");
  console.log(result02);
  var result03 = regExp.exec(ip03);
  console.log(" --- ip03: ", ip03, "---");
  console.log(result03);
  var result04 = regExp.exec(ip04);
  //var result04B = regExp.exec(ip04)[1]; // null - PROBLEM
  console.log(" --- ip04: ", ip04, "---");
  console.log(result04);
  // console.log(result04B);
  console.log(" --- ip05: ", ip05, "---");
  var result05 = regExp.exec(ip05);
  var result05B = regExp.exec(ip05)[1];
  console.log(result05);
  console.log(result05B);


}
```

RESULT

```
[20-05-12 23:54:45:052 CEST]  --- ip01:  256.12.2.0 ---
[20-05-12 23:54:45:054 CEST] null
[20-05-12 23:54:45:056 CEST]  --- ip02:  255.12.2.0 ---
[20-05-12 23:54:45:058 CEST] [ '255.12.2.0',
  '255.12.2.0',
  '2.',
  '2',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  '2',
  '0',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  '0',
  index: 0,
  input: '255.12.2.0',
  groups: undefined ]
[20-05-12 23:54:45:060 CEST]  --- ip03:  192.168..1 ---
[20-05-12 23:54:45:061 CEST] null
[20-05-12 23:54:45:063 CEST]  --- ip04:  10.12.12.12.12 ---   ****** is bad 
[20-05-12 23:54:45:064 CEST] [ '10.12.12.12',
  '10.12.12.12',
  '12.',
  '12',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  '12',
  '12',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  '12',
  index: 0,
  input: '10.12.12.12.12',
  groups: undefined ]
[20-05-12 23:54:45:066 CEST]  --- ip05:  010.060.090.002 ---
[20-05-12 23:54:45:068 CEST] null
[20-05-12 23:54:45:069 CEST] 010.060.090.002
```

If you think a 'valid' feature would be helpfull, vote up here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762591

### 2. VISUALISING the 'valid' / 'unvalid' *status* of the input with conditional formatting :

And the idea is then make it visual by 'conditional formatting'
(https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/conditional-format#apps-script)

All Help is more then welcome.

---

formula and script:

### Link the spreadsheet and google script :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HTgdC6Ss8oOvwVm86kbOdlt5jX8UyVmd-Eyo-oWhEGw

(only read access, if you want to test/check it out make a copy)

> REMARK : (continued)
>   [How can I dynamically apply a regular expression on change of a cell or in conditional format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027163/how-can-i-dynamically-apply-a-regular-expression-on-change-of-a-cell-or-in-condi?noredirect=1#62027163)
>
> **Google Apps Script; using Regular Expression on a dynamic way implemented, on change of a cell or in conditional format.**

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your goal? In your question, there are 2 directions like `1. VALIDATING the input with regular expression' (do you want to achieve this using Google Apps Script?)` and `2. VISUALISING the 'valid' / 'unvalid' status of the input with conditional formatting`. Which do you want to achieve using?

Comment: @Tanaike, yes indeed I would like to achieve to check/validate the input by regular expression if it is a valid IPv4  address (my pattern works). But unfortunately I don't succeed to get a proper output  ex boolean; valid / unvalid status. 
--- and then by conditional formatting in google script visualising
--- And then finally using it in google script as datavalidation for a range of cells :D
Long way to go

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, what result do you need? For example, when `256.12.2.0` is the input value, what result do you need? And in your current question, what answer do you want? It's the answer using the built-in formulas or Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks for your quick response.
Just like in the screen shot of formulas, there is an overview of the valid and unvalid examples, done by formula (and also casting the input to string). 
`256 ... `is **not** valid. SEE ALSO  reg exp demo : https://regexr.com/54fon  I just want the **exact match** as valid / correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, my 2 questions in my previous comment were not resolved. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So from your replying, I would like to check your question again. When I could correctly understand about your goal and current issue, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and updated question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213755/discussion-between-kris-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to output the boolean type when the IP addresses are checked using Google Apps Script.
- You want to check a column in the Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In this answer, as the regex for matching IPV4, `^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$` is used. [Ref](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html)
- In order to check and return the boolean type, I used `test()` for this.

#### Sample script:

The sample script is as follows. In this case, it supposes that there are the IP addresses in the column "A". And the output value is put to the column "B".

```
function myFunction() {
  const regExpPattIP = '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$';
  const regExp = new RegExp(regExpPattIP);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var res = values.map(([e]) => ([regExp.test(e.trim())]));
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note:

- When the following modification is reflected to above sample script, the cell color of the valid IP address is changed.

  - From

    ```
    var res = values.map(([e]) => ([regExp.test(e.trim())]));
    range.offset(0, 1).setValues(res);
    ```
  - To

    ```
    var colors = values.map(([e]) => ([regExp.test(e.trim()) ? "green" : null]));
    range.setBackgrounds(colors);
    ```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained. I used your sample IP addresses at the column "A". The result is put to the column "B".

[image]

#### References:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Dear Tanaike thank you very much for you answer. Despite of the language difference ... what is absolutely no problem. I hope I can learn of your input and experience ..

Your answer is good and well explained.
:D and very nice ligned up, what makes it reading very easy ... in contrast with my input.

Keep it safe and healthy ... hope to meet you here again (see chat)

Comment: Tanaike, I have stupid question. It works fine, but I have now an other issue, problem. When a cell is now unvalid or contains an unvalid IPv4 address. I'm not able to change it now.
I have to force and delete first the validation.

Comment: @kris Thank you for replying. About your new question, I cannot understand about `an other issue` which is `When a cell is now unvalid or contains an unvalid IPv4 address. I'm not able to change it now. I have to force and delete first the validation.`. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can you provide the detail of `an other issue`? When I could correctly understand about it, I can think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad.

Comment: sorry for the delay.
Finally, I am able to show you a working situation, which validates it dynamic. The validation of the PORT - is done with conditional formatting and the IP validation with help/aid rows and columns.

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027163/gas-on-a-dynamic-way-regular-expression-implementing-on-change-of-a-cell-or-i**

Comment: @kris Thank you for your response. I will check it.